# Allow Users Only Edit Their Profile?

Tags: login, user-roles, permissions, community

We want to create profiles for individuals/companies which would allow them to login to the backend and adjust their profile.

So essentially the admin of Wordpress would have access to all pages and profiles but the individual/company would only have access to their profile page - which they can then update. Where do I start with something like this?

Comment: When you say update their page - do you mean their profile page? The 'Subscriber' role only allows users to edit their profile by default.

Comment: @StephenHarris Sorry, I meant that an actual page would represent their profile. I guess forget the word profile for now - can a user login to the cms and only edit a page they have created? Therefore if a hundred people created a new page, I only want them to be able to edit their own page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `author` user role allows users to *add, edit, and delete their own pages and posts*, but disallows users to *edit or delete others' pages and posts*; however, it does not, out of the box, limit users to the creation of a single page or post.

If your intent is merely to allow users to create a public profile page, I would recommend creating a custom template that displays user meta data, that each user can manage from his/her own back-end profile page. If you need additional user meta data, simply add custom user meta data to the user profile page. That way, you can use custom templates to output the public profile pages using the user custom meta data, while being able to leave users in the `subscriber` user role, which prevents them from creating pages or posts.